# Getting pixel position of a text in an image

Tags: java, image-processing

I am working on a research project.The scenario is this.

I am taking the screenshot of my desktop and then I process  it using an API to get the position of a certain text on my Desktop.e.g , say I have the browser open on my desktop and I am on stackoverflow.Now I want to search the position of the logo **stackoverflow** on the screenshot taken.Then I want to simulate a click on it.I am using Java platform.

Now I have 2 questions:

1)Is there any free API(OCR) which I can use to process the screenshot to fetch text position (or can be done by some trick) and gives good results.

**Or Any way you can suggest that I can use (instead of taking screenshot and processing it) to get the position of any text on the screen.**

2)How can I simulate the click on the screen using the code by a background program running(I mean I have done it in Swing and other language UIs but this time its different as Now I want to click on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you right you want to move your mouse and click on the screen. That not that hard you could use the robot class from Java!

For example:

```
Robot rob = new Robot();
rob.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_ENTER );
```

or what ever, there are so much bottons and movements you could with it. A list of all methods you find [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

And your other question I can't answer. I think there is no API that is able to search a text and give you the position. But what I know is that the robot class is able to capture the screen and put it into a BufferedImage. With it you could compare two pictures.

Maybe you could get use of [this](http://asprise.com/product/ocr/index.php?lang=java) but I don't know if it is what you search.

Comment: Gerret:+1 for that `Robot` thing.I didn't knew it.That will make my task easy.

Comment: @InsaneCoder Edit a link for your text thing